# Tomcat maven plugin - Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, logging, tomcat7, slf4j, logback

When I launch my webapp in a standalone tomcat container, I see Flyway logging fine (it uses commons-logging if found, sout otherwise as stated by Axel below).

However, when I use the apache tomcat maven plugin (tomcat7-maven-plugin), I see the following:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Nothing fancy here.  Here's the complete code:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(...);
    flyway.migrate();
}

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.blah.conf.FlywayListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I'm using logback-classic for logging.  Jersey and Guice both log fine (though I removed them to narrow down the problem).

Here're the only logging related jars I see in my classpath:

```
logback-classic-1.0.13
logback-core-1.0.13
slf4j-api-1.7.5
```

Here's the dependency tree for slf4j:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ hello ---
[INFO] com.hello:hello:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
```

So my updated question is, why is there a difference using the tomcat maven plugin vs standalone?  I don't see any additional jars in the "target" folder where it's temporarily deployed.

UPDATE:
After adding jcl-over-slf4j the problem has gone away.

Comment: After adding jcl-over-slf4j the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flyway-core logging works as follows: If commons-logging is found use that, otherwise use System.out.

Please file a feature request in the issue tracker if you would like native SLF4J support.

As for your exception, that comes from something else.

Comment: Thank you Axel.  Strangely, the SLF4J warning only appears when I added those three lines of Flyway code.  If I remove them, the warning goes away - so I assumed it was Flyway.  I'll try to narrow down the problem further.

Comment: I narrowed down the problem - simple webapp with a single context listener which does a Flyway migration. The tomcat maven plugin (tomcat7-maven-plugin) seems to be the root cause. I'll update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This warning is emitted by the tomcat7-maven-plugin.

Declaring the plugin as:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

will provide a particular logging binding to the plugin's classpath, making the warning go away.